# Getting weather information for a specific place in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, weather

The Google Maps weather layer only shows "weather markers" in default places, which usually are main cities and towns.

Is it possible placing a weather marker in a specific place not covered by the default weather markers?
Documentation about weather layer management is really poor, there's only one paragraph in the layers docs page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#WeatherLayer

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is pretty clear:

> Enabling the weather layer will show current weather conditions from weather.com on your map, including icons that 
>   denote sun, clouds, rain and so on. Clicking on the weather icon for a particular area will open an info window with 
>   detailed data such as current humidity and wind conditions, as well as a four-day forecast.

You should be able to detailed weather for any "specific place" weather.com has data for.

Comment: Honestly, it does not seem to me to be so clear... The only phrase which makes deduct your conclusion would be the first: "Enabling the weather layer will show current weather conditions from weather.com on your map." It does not explain the places coverage weather.com has. Using an adverb such as "only" or, which is better, explaining that weather.com places database is limited, would have been quite clearer.